# Detecting if a player is in a storage GUI

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm building a game in Bedrock Edition and can't figure this out.

I need it so that when a player takes blocks out from a storage block and puts them into their hand while still in the storage GUI, the block they're standing on is /filled with the specific block they took out. I also need the blocks to be cleared from their inventory once they get out of the GUI.

How can I do this with commands?